# use a data.table variable as a function parameter on a nested list

Tags: r, data.table

Provided this example, I would like to calculate the sum of values inside lists in variable `b` according to the length determined by variable `a`.
Please consider the following reproducible example:

```
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a = 1:4)
dt[, b:= .(list(1:6))]
```

Now I want to calculate something like this:

```
dt[, c:= sum(b[[1]][1:a])]
```

Of course this results in a warning message and a result different from expected.

I also tried to use `apply`, but it returns an error because of an attempted NA/NaN operation:

```
dt[, c := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) sum(x[1][[1]][1:x[2]]))]
```

My expected result is:

```
> dt
   a           b  c
1: 1 1,2,3,4,5,6  1
2: 2 1,2,3,4,5,6  3
3: 3 1,2,3,4,5,6  6
4: 4 1,2,3,4,5,6 10
```

How can I achieve that?

(For the curious: I tried my best to provide a reproducible example. Actual data involve a forecast of the number of items delivered from a wharehouse, which is stored in a list variable, and the number of days it takes to replenish them. The sum of the forecast from day one to day n (the lead time) is the number of items at which the supply process needs to be started again --reorder point--).

**###### EDIT TO ADD #####**

Consider the following case:

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(1, 3, 3, 4), b = c(list(1:6), list(2:7), list(3:8), list(4:9)))
```

The expected result will be:

```
dt[, c]
# 1 9 12 22
```

Comment: If you're willing to load magrittr, there's `dt[, v := Map(extract, b, lapply(a, seq_len)) %>% sapply(sum)]` (just syntactic sugar on mt1022's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the operation is rowwise, we can use `mapply` instead of grouping by row:

```
dtt[, newCol := mapply(function(x, y) sum(y[1:x]), a, b)]
```

and personally I would avoid using `c` or `dt` for a variable or column name.